# Django - extend template from parent directory

Tags: django, django-templates

I have this templates structure:

dir1:
base.html
dir2: template.html

template.html must extend base.html:

```
{% extends '../dir1/base.html' %}
```

But it raises error:

> Caught TemplateDoesNotExist while rendering: ../dir1/base.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should set template dir (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-dirs) in settings.py and then use `{% extends 'dir/base.html' %}`.